# How to set up Qt Creator so that it shows up under Applications?

Tags: macos, qt, qt-creator

Admittedly, I'm a newbie on the Apple / Mac ecosystem...

On Max OS X, the default install from Qt Disk Image installs to the user's home directory (/Users/`whoami`). This creates thousands of files show up in the Mac OS Finder.

I've managed to install to /usr/local/Qt. However, the only way to launch Qt Creator is from the Terminal.

I'd like to know how to set up Qt Creator so the installed app shows up under Applications in Finder app.

Comment: How did you manage to install it in /usr/local ? Is there any references ? I have the same problem. I am using mac for 2 days only. I don't know how to uninstall the existing installation.

Answer (score 24):

Download the current version of Qt Creator:

https://download.qt.io/official_releases/qtcreator/

Open the DMG file. Drag the `Qt Creator` icon to the `Applications` shortcut which is in the DMG folder.

Alternatively install [homebrew](http://brew.sh/):

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Then install [brew cask](http://caskroom.io/)

```
brew install caskroom/cask/brew-cask
```

Once `brew cask` is installed you can install qt creator through that:

```
brew cask install qt-creator
```

Brew cask will install the application and it will appear in spotlight but not global `/Application` folder the because instead it creates a symbolic link to the `~/Applications` folder. If you want to have it show up in the global `/Applications` folder you'll need to manually link it yourself via the following command:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/qt-creator/3.4.0/Qt\ Creator.app/ /Applications/Qt\ Creator.app
```

If you already have Qt Creator somewhere on your system you could just link to it using the previous command.

Comment: The sudo command to create the link will need to be modified to point to the version that downloaded.  3.5.0 is the current version as of the time of this comment.

Answer (score 5):

for example ,if you install Qt5.7 in the default folder,that is under /Users/your user /, you can use this command

```
ln -s ~/Qt5.7.0/Qt\ Creator.app/ /Applications/
```

now you look at your launcher panel,and you will find it.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is what you want:

First off, if you don't already have it, get [homebrew](http://brew.sh/). It makes installing and updating certain applications/programs really easy. A helpful external tool ([cask](http://caskroom.io/)) can also be installed for more generic .app bundles. This includes qt creator and probably does what you want.

Comment: I'm sorry but homebrew is not the way to install Qt from disk images available at http://qt-project.org/downloads

Comment: @KamilKlimek The current download link contained within the `qt-creator` cask formula is https://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qtcreator/3.1/3.1.2/qt-creator-opensource-mac-x86_64-3.1.2.dmg. Seems to be what he is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Launch Qt Creator once from Terminal, then while it's running right click on Qt Creator in Dock, select Options->Keep in Dock. Or just drag it to change its position in Dock, it'll stay there even after you close it.

If you want it to live in Applications folder, just drag it there. If you press Cmd+Option while dragging to Applications, you'll create alias (shortcut) instead of copying the whole app bundle.

Comment: keeping Qt Creator in Dock must not be a good solution for many people, but putting an alias into the application folder will work.

Comment: Unlike the haters, I thought this was a great solution @Paul. Thanks. I needed to launch Qt Creator from this path `/Users/<your name>/Qt/Qt Creator.app/Contents/MacOS/Qt Creator`

Answer (score 0):

I used 
`ln -s ~/Qt/Qt\ Creator.app /Applications/`
to create symbolic link after Qt installation using the online installer.

Comment: This answer is essentially identical to the older one by _bowman han_.