# Could not find qmake configuration file default. Mac OS

Tags: macos, qt-creator

I have installed Qt Creator in the following way [How to set up Qt Creator so that it shows up under Applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24960176/how-to-set-up-qt-creator-so-that-it-shows-up-under-applications)

Then I made Git Clone project. In General Messages it writes

> Could not find qmake configuration file default.
>   Error while parsing file /... Giving up

`qmake -v` says QMake version `2.01a` Using Qt version `4.8.7` in `/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7/lib`

which `qmake` says `/usr/local/bin/qmake`

How to solve this problem?

Comment: I also have put qmake to the directory, where compiles are (/usr/bin)
But it continue says 'Could not find qmake configuration file default.' and when I try to open it from the terminal, it says that there is no qmake file, but there is

Comment: Don't you need to set `$QDIR`?

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this specific issue:

```
Could not find qmake configuration file default.
```

Review your Qt Creator default kit:

1. Tools > Options ...
2. Select Build & Run
3. Select your preferred kit
4. Click "Make Default" button
5. Click OK
6. Now reopen your project.

If you continue to have issues, you will need to review your Qt installation. Perhaps consider grabbing the latest one from https://www.qt.io/download/